# Laravel 5 not updating correctly

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and PHP 7.1 
I'm having an issue when updating one of my models. I use the same form for both create and update, create works as intended but update does not. The weird thing is I have another model that works exactly as intended but I can't find any difference between the code I use. This is my first Laravel project and I'm self taught so there may be things in my code that are not good practice, I welcome any constructive criticism.

When I try to update a checkbox attribute to false it always returns true. When I create the initial object I get the correct value for the checkbox both true and false however if the boolean value is true then I cannot set it to false. I'm not sure if this is an issue in blade or in my code. In the controller I have used dd($item) before the update and the value is true even though the checkbox is unchecked. In the model I have a cast to ensure the attributes are boolean, there is a mutator in the model to ensure the value is 0 or 1, and a similar feature in the request to ensure a value of 0 or 1. The two attributes I'm having issues with are has_accessories and has_services.

I'm also having an issue with updating a price field, I get an error on the update if the price has a comma in the value. The interesting thing is when I do dd($item) before the update the value does **not** have a comma in it. On the initial create I can save the object when price has a comma in it. When I omit the comma in the html page then there is no issue. There is a mutator in the model that removes any commas or $ and similar code in the request. The attribute I'm having issues with is price.

Here is the relevant code from the model:

```
class Item extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['item_type_id', 'item_category_id', 'item_condition_id', 'name', 
                           'description', 'serial_number', 'serial_accessory', 'size', 'price', 
                           'has_accessories', 'has_services', 'manafacturer', 
                           'manufacturer_serial_number', 'refrigerant_type'];
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
    protected $casts = ['has_accessories' => 'boolean', 'has_services' => 'boolean'];

    // mutators - also located in Requests\ItemRequest (custom form validation)
    protected function setPriceAttribute($value)
    { 
        if (isset($value)) {
            $this->attributes['price'] = str_replace(',', '', $value);
            $this->attributes['price'] = str_replace('$', '', $value);
        } else {
            $this->attributes['price'] = 0;
        }
    }

    protected function setHasAccessoriesAttribute($value) { $this->attributes['has_accessories'] = isset($value) ? $value : FALSE; }
    protected function setHasServicesAttribute($value) { $this->attributes['has_services'] = isset($value) ? $value : FALSE; }

    // accessors
    protected function getPriceAttribute($value) { return isset($value) ? number_format(round($value, 2), 2, '.', ',') : 0; }
```

Here is the relevant code from my controller:

```
    public function store(ItemRequest $itemRequest)
    {
//        dd($_POST);
        Item::create($itemRequest->request->all());
        session()->flash('alert', $itemRequest->request->get('name').' created.');

        return redirect('items');
    }
    public function update(Request $itemRequest, Item $item)
    {
        //dd($item);
        $item->update($itemRequest->request->all());
        session()->flash('alert', $item->name.' updated.');

        return back();
    }
```

Here is the request:

```
class ItemRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        // only allow if user is logged in
        return Auth::check();
    }
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'item_type_id' => 'required|integer|exists:item_types,id',
            'item_category_id' => 'required|integer|exists:item_categories,id',
            'item_condition_id' => 'required|integer|exists:item_conditions,id',
            'name' => 'required|between:1,50|string',
            'description' => 'required|string',
            'serial_number' => 'nullable|max:25|alpha_dash',
            'serial_accessory' => 'nullable|max:10|alpha_dash',
            'size' => 'nullable|alpha_num',
            'price' => 'nullable|numeric',
            'has_accessories' => 'required|boolean',
            'has_services' => 'required|boolean',
            'manufacturer' => 'nullable|string|max:30',
            'manufacturer_serial_number' => 'nullable|string|max:30',
            'refrigerant_type' => 'nullable|string|max:30'
        ];
    }

    protected function prepareForValidation()
    {
        $this->sanitizeInput();

        return parent::getValidatorInstance();
    }

    private function sanitizeInput()
    {
        // get the input
        $input = array_map('trim', $this->all());
        $input['has_accessories'] = isset($input['has_accessories']) ? $input['has_accessories'] : FALSE;
        $input['has_services'] = isset($input['has_services']) ? $input['has_services'] : FALSE;
        $input['price'] = empty($input['price']) ? null : str_replace(',', '', $input['price']);

        $this->replace($input);
    }
}
```

Here is the relevant blade code:

```
        <div class='col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-1 form-group margin_under_border'>
            <label for='price' class='form-label'>Price</label>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 form-group margin_under_border'>
            <input type='text' id='price' name='price' value="{{ old('price', isset($item) ? $item->price : null) }}" class='form-control'>
        </div>

        <div class='col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 form-group margin_under_border'>
            <label for='has_accessories' class='form-label'>Has Accessories</label>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 form-group margin_under_border'>
            <input type='checkbox' id='has_accessories' name='has_accessories' class='form-control' value=1 {{ (old('has_accessories', isset($item) ? $item->has_accessories : 1) == 1)? 'checked' : '' }}>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-1 col-sm-1 hidden-md hidden-lg'>
        </div>

        <div class='col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 form-group margin_under_border'>
            <label for='has_services' class='form-label'>Has Services</label>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 form-group margin_under_border'>
            <input type='checkbox' id='has_services' name='has_services' class='form-control' value=1 {{ (old('has_services', isset($item) ? $item->has_services : 1) == 1) ? 'checked' : '' }} >
        </div>
```

I appreciate any help with this. It's so frustrating to get stuck on such a simple action.

Update: When I use tinker I can successfully set the boolean attributes in the model to false. I cannot set the price attribute when it has a comma in it.

I have commented out all the code in my model and the request, I changed the update to just $item->update() instead of running it through the request, and I changed the checkbox code back to the original:

```
        <div class='col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 form-group margin_under_border'>
            @if (old('has_accessories', isset($item) ? $item->has_accessories : 1) == 1)
                <input type='checkbox' id='has_accessories' name='has_accessories' class='form-control' value=1 checked>
            @else
                <input type='checkbox' id='has_accessories' name='has_accessories' class='form-control' value=1>
            @endif
        </div>
```

and I'm still having the same issues. I thought it might have been a typo somewhere in the code causing it but it can't get simpler than an update statement. The thing I can't wrap my head around is if it's the checkbox code then why does it work as intended when creating but not when updating?

When I do dd($item) the value for the unchecked checkbox is not correct (if it was previously true) however when I do dd($_POST) the value is correct.

Comment: Why don't you use `@if` in your view instead. It would be more readable and understandable.

Comment: I agree it was just one of the many options I tried with the checkbox input.

Answer (score 0):

You could try another version of doing it in your `.blade`:

```
<input type='checkbox' id='has_services' name='has_services' class='form-control' value=1 
@if(isset($item))
    @if($item->has_services == 1)
        checked
    @endif
@endif
>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I actually had an if statement before for the entire checkbox, one without the checked and one with. I was just trying different options. I agree it's less readable this way just happens to be one of the many options I've tried. None of the variants including the one posted above have changed the outcome.